# Как задать событие создаваемому элементу в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, события, onclicklistener

Я хочу создать элемент `div` `JS` кодом
Я делаю так:

```js
var node = document.createElement("div");
node.className = "el"
node.onclick = this.remove();
...
```

Дальше идёт `append` `node` к ещё одному `div`

Результат:

```html
<div class="el">
```

Вопрос: **Где `onclick`?**

Я пытался сделать вот так:

```js
node.onclick = "this.remove()"
node.onclick = function() {this.remove()}
node.onclick = () => {this.remove()}
node.onclick = this.remove();
node.addEventListener("onclick", (event) => {node.remove()}, false)
```

Ничего из этого не работает и даже не выдаёт ошибку, зато если просто ввести `node.remove()`, то оно удаляет элемент

То же самое и с другими событиями элемента

Ну так как мне добавить событие нажатия (желательно через `node.onclick`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

//вариант 1 (вы присваиваете результат функции вызванной у непонятного контекста)

```
node.onclick = function(){this.remove()};
```

//вариант 2

```
node.addEventListener('click',function(){
  this.remove()
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var node = document.createElement("div");
node.className = "el";
node.onclick = function() {
  this.remove()
};
document.getElementById('test').append(node);
```

```css
#test {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.el {
  border: 2px solid lightgreen;
  width: 120px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Обработчик добавляется через addEventListener.
[https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp#:~:text=The%20addEventListener()%20method&text=You%20can%20add%20many%20event,i.e%20the%20window%20object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp#:%7E:text=The%20addEventListener()%20method&text=You%20can%20add%20many%20event,i.e%20the%20window%20object).

Comment: Я пытался добавить и через `addEventListener`, но спасибо вам, я понял, что вместо `onclick` надо писать `click`